# ReactJS, Change page content after button onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem changing the content in page. 
I already tried a lot of internet hints.

Point: After opening page, I want to see `loadDepartment` and a button. And if I click the button "emp". Content of whole page change to `loadEmployees`. I need this without refreshing the page.

```js
componentDidMount() {
      return this.initializeContent("hie")
}

initializeContent(choose) {
      if(choose == "emp") {
          console.log("page choosed:", choose);
          return this.loadEmployees();
      }
      else if(choose == "hie") {
          console.log("page choosed:", choose);
          return this.loadDepartment();
      }
      else {
          console.log("not found user choice -", choose);
          return (<div>There is a problem with loading of hierarchy pagae</div>)
      }
  }
  
loadDepartment() {
  return (<div>apple</div>)
}
loadEmployees() {
  return (<div>orange</div>)
}
  
render() {
  return (<div>
        {this.componentDidMount()}
        <button className="userReq" data-name="emp" onClick={this.initializeContent.bind(this, "emp")}>blabla</button>
  </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch the internal state of the component. The render() function is special and the return value gets used by React, but the loadEmployees() function doesn't have the same special status. Here's the sort of thing you should do:

```js
var MyComponent = React.createClass({


      loadDepartment() {
        this.setState({
          view: "department"
        });
      },
      loadEmployees() {
        this.setState({
          view: "employees"
        });
      },

      render() {
        if (this.state.view === "employees") return <div>orange</div>;
        if (this.state.view === "department") return <div > apple </div>;
        return (<div>
          <button className = "userReq"
          data-name = "emp"
          onClick = { this.loadEmployees } >blabla </button> 
          </div>)
        }
      });
```

The component will automatically re-render whenever you call setState(), and it will use the new value of this.state to determine what to render.

Comment: Thank you, but there is error in console. "hierarchy.js:144 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'view' of null" - Problem is, that this code is in bigger project, and i showed you just a part. Because there are not orange and apple in loaddep, and loademp. But they are full of another code. I got, what you wrote to me, and probably, there is no chance to solve this problem by me. Iam frontend developer, and just helping with this part.

Comment: The snippet isn't intended to run (I just copied yours and improved it). The point is for you to read the code understand the technique - in the onClick handler use setState() to change the internal state of the component, and then in render() you can switch on the value of this.state. Is that clear, or do would you like me to explain it differently?

Comment: It is totally clear from your side. Problem is, that i dont understand a technique of react. I have to watch some tutorials.

Comment: i solved the problem with our backend programator. It is same logic as you describe. Thank you :)